# Automatically update custom field in all posts of a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, cron

I have a custom post type ("fecha") that contains past events (birthdates of famous people, historical dates, etc). Within these posts, a custom field ("aniversario") calculates how many years have passed since the original date.

This value is stored when the post is created and saved, so I need to update these custom posts (all of them) every year so that this custom field keeps being valid. I am trying to use cron (with a daily schedule) to call an update_post_meta, without success. All posts in these custom post type are private and appear only in the admin side.

The website is personal and for non-comercial pourposes (I´m a freelance science writer, this is an attempt to build a personal editorial calendar, wich would help me enormously).
Any help pointing errors in code or something missing, would be great. The code is as follows (it is located in my functions.php):

```
function run_update_fecha_cron_job() {

    $posts = get_posts([
        'post_type' => 'fecha',
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // getting all posts of a post type
        'no_found_rows' => true, // speeds up a query significantly and can be set to 'true' if we don't use pagination
        'fields' => 'ids' // again, for performance
    ]);

    // now check meta and update custom fields for every post
    foreach ($posts as $post_id) {

        /*
         * calculate how many years have passed by sustracting the value from
         * another custom field called "wpcf-ano" to current year, then store calculated value in
         * variable "$aniversario", wich should be "1" if nothing is stored in "wpcf-ano"
         */
        $ano = get_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-ano', TRUE);
        if (!empty($ano)) {
            $year_diff = date("Y") - $ano;
            $aniversario = $year_diff;
        } else {
            $aniversario = 1;
        }

        // update custom field
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'aniversario', $aniversario);
    }

}

// Schedule Cron Job Event
function update_fecha_cron_job() {

    if (!wp_next_scheduled('run_update_fecha_cron_job')) {
        wp_schedule_event(current_time('timestamp'), 'daily', 'run_update_fecha_cron_job');
    }

}
add_action('wp', 'update_fecha_cron_job');
add_action('run_update_fecha_cron_job', 'run_update_fecha_cron_job');
```

Comment: to avoid this treatment, it's better to store the birthday date on the meta and calculate the years on display.

Comment: I think that´s exactly what I am currently doing. Birthdate year is saved in a custom field ("wpcf-ano") and used to calculate the value of another custom field ("aniversario", depicting the number of years that have passed since then). Not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: for "wpcf-ano", I think it's ok. but for "aniversario" it would be easier to calculate this value only when you want to display the value, that should not use to much resources.

Comment: I want to show and use that value ("aniversario") as a column and filter in the admin post list for this custom post type ("fecha"). For that reason, I need it to be stored as a custom field. Could you detect something wrong in the code I posted? Thanks.

Comment: verify that "get_post" return what you need. by default only published posts are returned.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your understanding. It´s hard for me to check the code since the cron job runs daily (and my coding ability is quite basic). I´ve added inside the get_posts an argument to retrieve private posts ('post_status' => 'private',). I´ll see if that works. Thanks again.

Comment: to debug, add this code `add_action("wp_loaded", function () {
 
 if (isset($_GET["test-cron-5489754564z"])) {
  do_action("run_update_fecha_cron_job");
  exit();
 }
 
});` and the go to url `.../wp-admin/?test-cron-5489754564z` to launch the action

Comment: Thanks. The result is a completely white page, nothing is loaded. The rest of the site is loaded correctly, just fails with the url you gave. Does that mean that get_posts is retrieving nothing? What query can I use, then?

Comment: Also, I added an echo "hola"; at the end of the function "run_update_fecha_cron_job" but still nothing is shown in that url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the third argument of `wp_schedule_event` is a action to call :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

then you need to hook the fonction at the action like this :

```
add_action("run_update_fecha_cron_job", "run_update_fecha_cron_job");
```

Comment: Now it works! Many thanks! I add it to the code above so to have everything together.

Comment: in the code above you removed the code for the hook `wp` but you need the two of them. on the action `wp` you define the cron if it doesn't exist and and on the action `run_update_fecha_cron_job` you run the treatment.

Comment: Is it now correct?